# Any Link or Documeny for HBASE implementation in cluster

Tags: hadoop, hbase

Any one can help me in HBASE installation and configuration in cluster environment(I have 10 node cluster in AWS)?

I spent a lot of time but nothing came out. I tried many salutations which got from google , but unfortunately noting works.

Present situation, All services are running in master and slave but not able to "list" or create table in Hbase.

I guess I am doing something wrong in some where.

Please provide any URL or document for step by step installation process and setup process for  HBASE in multi cluster.

One more point do I need to install/run zookeeper in master and slave node separately for HBASE.

Any help will be highly appropriated.....

Thanks a lot .....

Comment: Could you please provide what error messages you getting for HBase table creation ???   I used CDH 5.7 and through that HBase service.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hbase/hbase_installation.htm  you can follow this link,I found it's pretty simple and useful.

Comment: @Ankita thanks a lot for your response. Error I am getting ...                 hbase(main):001:0> list
TABLE                                                                                                                                           
2016-07-11 16:06:03,600 ERROR [main] client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2016-07-11 16:06:03,815 ERROR [main]